# Environment variables are different for dll than exe

Tags: c++, variables, dll, environment

I'm debugging an 64-bit application where c# exe is using native c++ dll, on Windows 7. It seems environment variables are different for these two, even though they are both executing in the same process. How is it possible that calling System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable has no effect on values returned by getenv()?

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/senthil/archive/2009/10/13/when-what-you-set-is-not-what-you-get-setenvironmentvariable-and-getenv.aspx

Answer (score 7):

The environment variables are just a blob of data which gets passed by windows to the process when it starts. The runtime functions you are using (The BCL for System.Environment and the CRT for getenv) are probably making copies of the environment during startup, which means they are not operating on the same "environment" variables.

Conceptually they must do this because otherwise there would need to be some way to synchronize them accessing the environment.

Comment: Is there any way to get around this? So that dlls can communicate by setting environment variables.

Comment: You could either build something yourself which operated on its own copy of the environment (which you get from the windows API), or you could expose one of the environment sets to the other side (either expose an API from the DLL to allow the exe to call the CRT env APIs or the other way around). If you're going to go that far, then why bother using environment variables at all - just build a different way of communicating?

Comment: Or you could use the windows APIs in the C++ DLL instead of get/setenv - from the article linked above it sounds like that uses the same copy of the environment as .net uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below function. You need to pass the EnvironmentVariableTarget as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget.aspx basing on your requirement.

public SetEnvironmentVariable(
    string variable,
    string value,
    EnvironmentVariableTarget target
)