# Setting environmrnt variables for DLL's in ms-windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, environment-variables

We have a C/C++ application which links in a DLL *(CPython in this case, though thats a detail)*.

The problem we face is the DLL's environment variables are not derived from the `.EXE`, rather the environment that launches the `.EXE`.

So `putenv` env vars are ignored.

It seems theres no good way to explicitly set env vars for a DLL (would be interested if there was), so an alternative is simply to use some startup process.

We could use a `.BAT` file, users are used to unzipping opening the `.EXE` Is there a conventional way to create a stub `.EXE` for the sole purpose to set env vars? (and pass `argv` to the main application?).

---

Note, this is a known issue:

- [Environment variables are different for dll than exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153547/environment-variables-are-different-for-dll-than-exe)
- CPython issues: http://bugs.python.org/issue16129

Comment: Environment variables are always a per-process thing, they are not bound to the executable or DLL. What I'm wondering is when exactly you are setting these vars. If you expect any changes to be reflected that are made after Python initialization, I'm pretty sure you are out of luck. Similarly I wouldn't expect changes made in Python to be reflected throughout the process either.

Comment: get/putenv() is trouble, the native environment is Unicode.  There's hanky-panky in the CRT to buffer the 8-bit version.  Combine that with CPython having its own CRT copy distinct from yours, and thus its own CRT state, and trouble with your updates with putenv() not visible in CPython is explained.

Comment: Yes, am aware we cant easily set an env var in a DLL, this is why the question asks about using stubs to set an initial env var state.

Comment: It may not be necessary to use a stub.  Typically any particular DLL will be either using the native environment (in which case you can use SetEnvironmentVariable) or a particular C runtime (in which case you can explicitly call that runtime's environment functions using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress).

Comment: @Harry Johnston - does this work when the EXE is linked against the DLL? (its loaded on initialization)

Comment: It should do, depending on when the DLL retrieves the environment variables in question from the runtime.